# What technology uses this tree games app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I found these 3 app on Play Store and want to base my learning course on what tehnology are they make.

1. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TreetopCrew.VirtualBeggar
2. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.outerminds.tubular
3. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nanobit.cheftown

So my questions are how to make it and focus my learning on technologies they use. What frameworks is best to use and stuff like that.

I know to make basics app till now, with standard design and fuctionality, but want to learn more.
I know that the last one is little more complex, but I have a free time and want to learn, so any help will be appreciate.
Thx

Comment: Feel free to contact the developers of those apps and ask them what they used.

Comment: Sorry but why negative rate?! I am ask already one of them and they dont want to answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suppose you received down votes as this is not really a question for stackoverflow. As commonsware stated, it is best practice to reach out to the developers and see if they are willing to divulge any info on what they used to develop their apps. As well there are multiple resources out there for starting game development in android. One that comes to my mind is XDA, but even just using google to dig around.

Here is a link to a game development thread on XDA
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1753131

And here is a link to the development thead mentioned in XDA
http://www.kilobolt.com

Stackoverflow is more designed and targeted to specific code problems/questions. It is not meant for individuals to ask for "how do i make this" questions.

For reference, please see the link below on what should be asked here on Stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "...this is not really a question for stackoverflow." - Then please don't answer it. If you answer questions that don't belong here, people will continue to take that as evidence that they can ask off-topic questions.

Comment: Ok guys dont be angry I was found also almost same Q here and with positive votes.. Im not one who making shity content here..

Comment: @Mike you are correct, I shouldn't have said anything and just let this get down voted to oblivion. Ehh the deed is done I suppose